# Using coupled system of PDEs in modelica

Tags: modelica

Just few questions, i hope someone will find time to answer :).

What if we have COUPLED model example: system of n indepedent variables X and n nonlinear partial differential equations PDEf(X,PDEf(X)) with respect to TIME that depends of X,PDEf(X)(partial differential equation depending of variables X ). Can you give some advice? Here is one example:

Let’s say that c is output, or desired variable. Let’s say that r is independent variable.Partial differential equation looks like:

∂c/∂t=D*1/r+∂c/∂r+2(D* (∂^2 c)/(∂r^2 ))
D=constant 
r=0:0.1:Rp- Matlab syntaxis, how to represent same in Modelica (I use integrator,but didn't work)?

Here is a code (does not work):

```
model PDEtest
/* Boundary conditions
1. delta(c)/delta(r)=0  for  r=0
2. delta(c)/delta(r)=-j*d for  r=Rp*/
parameter Real Rp=88*1e-3; // length
parameter Real initialConc=1000;
parameter Real Dp=1e-14;
parameter Integer np=10; // num. of points
Real cp[np](start=fill(initialConc,np));
Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Integrator r(k=1); // independent x1
Real j;
protected 
parameter Real dr=Rp/np;
parameter Real ts= 0.01; // for using when loop (sample(0,ts) )
algorithm 
j:=sin(time); // this should be indepedent variable like x2
r.u:=dr;
while r.y<=Rp loop
for i in 2:np-1 loop
der(cp[i]):=2*Dp/r.y+(cp[i]-cp[i-1])/dr+2*(Dp*(cp[i+1]-2*cp[i]+cp[i-1])/dr^2);
end for;
if r.y==Rp then
cp[np]:=-j*Dp;
end if;
cp[1]:=if time >=0 then initialConc else initialConc;
end while;
annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2")));
end PDEtest;
```

Here are more questions:

1. This code don’t work in OpenModelica 1.8.1, also don’t work in Dymola 2013demo. How can we have continuos function of variable c, not array of functions ?
2. Can we place values of array cp in combiTable? And how?
3. If instead “algorithm” stay “equation” code can’t be succesfull checked.Why? In OpenModelica, error is :could not flattening model :S.
4. Is there any simplified way to use a set of equation (PDE’s) that are coupled? I know for PDEs library in Modelica, but I think they are complicated. I want to write a function for solving PDE and call these function in “main model”, so that output of function be continuos function of “c”.I don’t know what for doing with array of functions.
5. Can you give me advice how to understand Modelica language, if we “speak” like in Matlab? For example: Values of independent variable r,we can specife in Matlab, like r=0:TimeStep:Rp…How to do same in Modelica? And please explain me how section “equation” works, is there similarity with Matlab, and is there necessary sequancial approach?
   Cheers :)

Comment: It is sad how much it bothers me that StackOverflow does not support MathJax like MathExchange.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to answer your question, since you assuming that Modelica ~ Matlab, but that's not the case. So I won't comment your code, since it's really wrong. Let me give you an example model to the [burger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation). Maybe you could use it as starting point.

```
model burgereqn
 Real u[N+2](start=u0);
 parameter Real h = 1/(N+1);
 parameter Integer N = 10;
 parameter Real v = 234;
 parameter Real Pi = 3.14159265358979;
 parameter Real u0[N+2]={((sin(2*Pi*x[i]))+0.5*sin(Pi*x[i])) for i in 1:N+2};
 parameter Real x[N+2] = { h*i for i in 1:N+2};
equation
 der(u[1]) = 0;
 for i in 2:N+1 loop
    der(u[i]) = - ((u[i+1]^2-u[i-1]^2)/(4*(x[i+1]-x[i-1])))
                + (v/(x[i+1]-x[i-1])^2)*(u[i+1]-2*u[i]+u[i+1]);
 end for;
 der(u[N+2]) = 0;
end burgereqn;
```

Your further questions:

1. cp is an continuous variable and the array is representing 
   every discretization point.
2. Why you should want to do that, as far as I understand cp is
   your desired solution variable.
3. You should try to use almost always equation section
   algorithm sections are usually used in functions. I'm pretty 
   sure you can represent your desire behaviour with equations.
4. I don't know that library, but the hard thing on a pde is the
   discretization and the solving it self. You may run into issues
   while solving the pde with a modelica tool, since usually 
   a Modelica tool has no specialized solving algorithm for pdes.
5. Please consider for that question further references. You could 
   start with [Modelica.org](https://www.modelica.org/publications).

Comment: Thank you, example was helpful and you answered me a question 5 with example :). And library is here https://www.modelica.org/libraries/PDELib

Comment: An important thing to consider when solving PDEs in Modelica is that since Modelica doesn't have a concept of "basis functions", you must first discretize your problem into a set of ODEs before tools can really work with your problem (Willi's answer provides an excellent example of this).  As such, the spatial variability of your solution is not present in the Modelica solution.  In other words, your solution will be continuous in time, but discrete in space. You could always reconstruct a spatially continuous solution from the discrete values by reconstructing the underlying basis functions.

Comment: Regarding #3, it is important to understand that Modelica is a declarative language, not an imperative language.  Your goal is to describe the problem in mathematical (not algorithmic terms).  I think that is at the heart of this issue of "speaking MATLAB" vs. "speaking Modelica".  It is actually quite a liberating change once you get used to it.

Comment: Regarding #4, my experience is that for elliptic and parabolic PDEs you don't usually have many problems in Modelica.  However, with hyperbolic PDEs, you can get into trouble because of the CFL condition.

Comment: Finally, for #5 you might consider buying a copy of [my book](http://bit.ly/ModelicaBook) (which includes discussion of PDEs, BTW). I also plan to cover the topic in my [new book](http://kck.st/PXZj40).

Comment: Thank you Michael. About the same topic. I have another problem with solver.I used parabolic PDE's, algebraic equation simultaneous,all in equation section, and controle the variables in algorithm section.Also  i used Euler integration method(Dassl is too slow).I recive error for solving nonlinear differential system at time 0.2 (or some another value).Mathematically system is well computed(with respect to spatial discretization). Which integration method is best for solving this type of system? Do you have some example? Best regard.

Comment: I simulate model in OM (1.9.1).Best solution is to use discrete system of equation,but OM don't allow this way (becaous of using derivatives).

Comment: @willi I tried to run your code. it runs find but all the u[i]s are constant. is it ok or I'm making a mistake here?

Comment: @Foad The action just happens in the first 1 ms.